# Connecting Azure Ubuntu VM to VPN

Tags: vpn, virtual-machines, openvpn, azure

I have an Azure Virtual Machine with Ubuntu 16.04 on it.
I need to connect it to a VPN.

**Note:** I dont need to create a VPN. I already have an OpenVPN server, I just need the VM to connect to it.

I was able to do it from the Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, but the controls on Azure VM are greyed out.

I have done `sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn-gnome`.
When I import the .conf file, the other cert files get loaded as well, but the button to create the VPN is disabled.

Is it the case that Azure does not allow VMs to be connected to someone else's VPN Server, or do I need to do something more?

Comment: I expect to be a config problem in your VPN client setup.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to configure Azure Vnet with VPN Site-to-Site or Point-to-Site.

I don't think that Microsoft allows native VPN to pass from their VMs.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this in my lab. It turns out that this issue is caused by remote accessing. If we remote to a Ubuntu desktop on a physical machine, this button is grey out too.

As a workaround, we are able to establish the VPN with command line.

**openvpn --config** *the_path_of_your_config_file*